# get json data from service to page in ionic 3

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to load a JSON from remote server which I already obtained in a service using http.get(), but I can't get the data from my service into my page. I can see the json data is loaded in the service in console.log but can't find a way to get it into my page so I can use those data in my UI. Does anybody see what i'm doing wrong here?

here is the code of my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';


@Injectable()
export class MyService {
returnedData;
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello MyService Provider');
  }

  getRemoteData(){
      console.log('Hello inside getRemoteData');
      this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?inc=gender,name,email,phone,picture,location').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.returnedData=data;
      });
 return returnedData;
  }

}
```

here is my page

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyService } from '../../providers/my-service';



@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    myJson;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public serviceOne: MyService) {
  }

  ionViewDidload(){
      console.log('Hello MyService called');
      this.myJson=this.serviceOne.getRemoteData;
      console.log('myJson');
  }

  getRandomSpan(){
    return Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
  };
}
```

I want to get the value of the json I received from server into myJson variable.
so I can use those data into UI.

Comment: are you getting some error on the console ?

Comment: yes when I try to return the json response from getRemoteData(), I get this - "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: co.myJson.results is undefined". but if I don't return anything from getRemoteData() program runs just fine. but my objective is to receive the json in my page.